# Mix two asymmetrical list in python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a,b)))
['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd', '5', 'e']
```

As you can see, I have two asymmetrical list and I want to mix them like above. The problem is it ignore the last item.

Expected:
`['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd', '5', 'e', 'f']`

Actual:
`['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd', '5', 'e']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `itertools` in the first place, I assume you want this to work on any iterables, not just lists, and ideally without eagerly listifying them first. Otherwise, just do this:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a,b))) + a[len(b):] + b[len(a):]
```

---

The [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) function *almost* does what you want out of the box, but it inserts a `fillvalue` (default `None`) for each slot once the shorter iterable runs out. If your values are all truthy, you can just filter those out with `if i` as in [Ajax1234's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49483350/908494), or `filter` with `None` as the predicate, but if your values can be anything in Python, even `None`, the only way to do it gets pretty clunky:

```
_sentinel = object()
[elem for elem in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=_sentinel)) 
 if elem is not _sentinel]
```

---

But you can look at how `zip_longest` works and do the same thing yourself, only generating "incomplete" tuples instead of "filled-in" tuples, and then call it like this:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip_longest_nofill(a, b)))
```

Although making a variant of the `zip_longest` code from the docs that's easy enough to explain in an SO answer is a bit challenging, so maybe it's better to use an explicit loop:

```
def zip_longest_nofill(*args):
    empty = object()
    its = [iter(arg) for arg in args]
    while True:
        vals = (next(it, empty) for it in its)
        tup = tuple(val for val in vals if val is not empty)
        if not tup:
            return
        yield tup
```

I think this version is a lot easier to understand (although it was actually a bit harder to write…)

Of course if the only thing you're ever going to use `zip_longest_nofill` for is to implement your `flattened_zip_nofill`, it's even easier to just inline it into the flattening part, at which point you end up with basically the two-liner in the last section.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `chain`, use `zip_longest`:

```
import itertools
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
new_results = [i for b in itertools.zip_longest(a, b) for i in b if i is not None]
```

Output:

```
['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd', '5', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: That will add spurious `None` values.

Comment: @abarnert yes, however, they can be filtered out of the final result.

Comment: Sure, but if the original lists can have any falsey values like `0` or `''` or, worse, `None`, it'll filter them out too.

Comment: You can solve that by using `_sentinel=object()`, passing `fillvalue=_sentinel` to `zip_longest`, and using `if i is not _sentinel`, but at that point it's not much simpler than just writing a loop…

Comment: Also, you're using `zip_longest` instead of `zip`, not instead of `chain`. (What you've replaced the `chain` with is a nested comprehension, which has no semantic difference here.)

Comment: If there are originally None in the lists, it will also be filtered out, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just manually append the remaining:

```
def mix(a, b):
    c = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a,b)))
    c += a[len(b)] + b[len(a):]
    return c
```

One liner:

```
mix = lambda a, b: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a,b))) + a[len(b)] + b[len(a):]
```

Comment: `mix(b, a)` is almost certainly not what he wants. I'm pretty sure you want to remove the `if` and just do `c += b[len(a):] + a[len(b):]` or something less terse.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks I didn't realise it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but it's not very elegant

```
lst = []
for i in range(temp = max(len(a), len(b))):
    if i < len(a): lst.append(a[i])
    if i < len(b): lst.append(b[i])

lst
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try itertools zip_longest:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

import itertools

output=[]
for i in itertools.zip_longest(a,b):
    if i[0]==None:
        output.append(i[1])
    else:
        output.extend([i[0],i[1]])

print(output)
```

output:

```
['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd', '5', 'e', 'f']
```